# Cannot get query in Google App Engine database

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Google App engine seems very confusing. I am trying to fetch data stored in the server. But nothing is fetched.
Down, you will find the code. I donot get what is wrong.
Code:

```
def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        timetable_query = Timetable.query(ancestor = tt_key(user.email()))
        timetable = timetable_query.fetch(10)

        template_values = {
                'timetable':  timetable
            }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('main.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
        timetable = Timetable(parent = tt_key(user.email()))
        timetable.owner = user;
        timetable.courses = self.request.get('courses')
        timetable.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

The data is going in but not coming out. *-*

Edit:
The ndb model class is like so:

```
class Timetable(ndb.Model):
    owner = ndb.UserProperty()
    courses = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    shared = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

and the template like so:

```
var storedCourses = "{{ timetable.courses }}";
```

Comment: How have you reached your 'nothing is fetched' conclusion? What does your template loook like?

Comment: I'll edit it to include it

Comment: @Greg Done! Is the template ok?

Comment: Ok @Greg You led me to the answer. The problem was in the template. If you write the answer with a link to describe how to jinja templates, i'll accept it =)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you can use logging to inspect your variables. Just `import logging` and debug:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

In this case the problem was in the template which you would have noticed if you had logged the values on your request handler.